# Support Ubuntu, quit Windows

Tags: discussion, ubuntu-community, windows

When I went to purchase a Laptop, I found that most comes with an installed Windows. I think this is a kind of business trick that Windows is using to keep its popularity. People are forced to pay for Windows no matter whether you like it or not. As a community which strongly support Ubuntu, do we need to or are we doing anything against it ?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundling_of_Microsoft_Windows#The_.22Windows_tax.22, https://www.fsf.org/blogs/community/a-victory-for-free-software-over-the-microsoft-tax

Comment: @muru:It is good to know. It is true in the case with desktops where we can buy the components and assemble it without Windows. Now a days many people used to do this. But still it is not the case with many Laptops. Many comes with a pre-installed Windows.

Comment: You may be interested to know that many of the larger manufacturers now have Linux versions of their laptops and desktops.  Ubuntu at Dell springs to mind, but also HP, IBM, and others offer Linux pre-installed.

Comment: I prefer Windows preinstalled so I don't need to purchase it again as I have legitimate copies :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the place to discuss this. You may want to instead talk about this on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.com) or [Ubuntu Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com)

Comment: In that case, I am truely sorry since it is my first post here in meta.